# My ADSL connection keeps dropping

Tags: connection, cable, adsl

For weeks my internet connection dropping about every 15-30 minutes. Then it comes back after 2-5 minutes. I reported the problem to my ISP, after a day they told me the problem is telephone cables in my apartment and I should repair it. But after midnight, my internet connection is rarely dropping. So If the problem is my telephone cable how my connection is getting better at midnight?. Here are my some dsl values:

--20.00(HOUR)--

noise safety coefficient (dB) (U/D): 8.4 / 8.1

line attenuation (dB) (U/D): 39 / 21

output power (dBm) (U/D): 12 / 21

---

--01.00(HOUR)--

noise safety coefficient (dB) (U/D): 16.8 / 16.1

line attenuation (dB) (U/D): 38 / 21

output power (dBm) (U/D): 12 / 21

---

Answer (score 2):

To blame internal house wiring is a bit of a diversion of attention away from
other problems. The principal way internal wiring fails, is if the
premises are in close proximity to salt air contamination causing corrosion problems. Internal wiring is reasonably well protected from the elements, bird poop and plastic destroying UV rays.
The problem usually lies with a badly degraded external copper network.

"Noise safety coefficient" is the same as "SNR margin". It seems that
repeated noise on the line has caused the ISP's equipment to increase your SNR,
resulting in less disconnections, but also in lower line speed.
I note that the value has gone up from about 8 db to 16 db, which is close
to the maximum.

The article [Broadband SNR Margin Tweak](http://www.increasebroadbandspeed.co.uk/SNR-tweak) contains much useful information
and says :

> The exchange equipment attempts to set the downlink connection speed
>   such that there is a sufficiently high SNR margin to guarantee a
>   reliable connection (without regular drops and/or an unacceptable
>   number of errors). This specific margin that the exchange tries to
>   achieve is called the target SNR margin. The higher the target SNR
>   margin, the lower your connection speed.
>
> As part of the Digital Line Management process, the exchange equipment
>   continuously monitors your broadband connection, for example recording
>   the number of times that it drops and the number of errors it suffers.
>   If the line experiences any issues (such as bursts of errors at a
>   particular time), the exchange equipment can increase the target SNR
>   margin – usually in steps of 3 dB. This action – aimed at stabilising
>   the line – reduces the connection speed.
>
> Once the BT exchange equipment has increased the target SNR margin, it
>   can take days for the target SNR margin to be reduced and, in some
>   cases, it is never reduced.

I believe that you experience network congestion and extra line noise during the
day, which will cause SNR to automatically rise in stages until the connection
stabilizes, but lowering line speed.

The most likely reasons for this is either bad quality of the lines
infrastructure or the ISP's equipment, or your ISP having over-committed
its lines, or some interference caused by adjacent commercial equipment.

According to the [SG DSL Speed Calculator](http://www.speedguide.net/dsl_speed_calc.php), your Downstream Attenuation of 21
indicates a distance of about 1.5 km, which means enough chances for bad
wiring and interference.

The above article I linked lists some ways to manually adjust the SNR
values through the router, but that is not a good solution.
If your ISP will not fix the problem, you might need to consider
some alternatives. Maybe trying other routers is also an idea.

Comment: My ISP suggests me to renew my telephone cables in my apartment. I could try but my router is pretty new.

Comment: It's always possible that the ISP is right, although I judge it unlikely - why would your internal lines works better at night? You should measure and compare your line speed at times when you have good and bad connections, using a short speed test like [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/). If the problem is noise, then it will be slower when the connection seems better. If the problem is the ISP over-committing the line, then the speed may be similar.

Comment: Last 5 days my connection is good, no droppings. I did not do anything actually. I'm waiting, if it happens again. Thank you for support

Comment: If you did nothing, then the ISP did. Maybe some routine maintenance has fixed the problem. Or maybe your complaint had a result, even if by telephone they gave you the stock answer - blaming your installation for the problem. Or maybe even the source for the interference on the line has shut down (if it returns again then this is the likeliest supposition).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to plug directly the modem to the phone line and see if you get improvement. You should also see if you have a capacitors that were used in old phone plugs in some countries (see pic).

[image: DSL]

Know that usually, interference can come from everything that has uses electromagnetic waves OR physical damage (like wet on the cables), faulty filter, or phone line installation close to electrical disturbance sources.

If your DSL subscription line is **equal or lower** than 8Mbps you can try to configure your router to synchronize with DSLAM using the **G.dmt norm (ADSL1)** instead of **ADSL2+** (G992.5). It's more stable, and stresses way less the line than the other synchronization mode.

(same principle can be done with 12Mbps and ADSL**2**, *not 2+* )

Comment: It' s already plugged directly. My ISP said that it might be cable oxidation. But if problem is cable oxidation why my connection is not bad at after midnight?

Comment: It can be wet, it's deadly for the DSL lines, but usually wet denies proper synchronization rates. Does it changes ? (down/up steams)

Comment: It's been like that for 10-11 days. Could it be wet for days?

Comment: depends on where you live, we had a case where the client's line was constantly humidified by the weather every day. but can you tell us if the sync rates change ?

Comment: what exactly should I do to see sync rates change?

Comment: in the router's page you can see what rate your modem negotiated with the DSLAM central. (e.g., 8190Kbps/1022Kbps  Down/Up)

Comment: Upstream line rate (kbit/s):
797,
Downstream line rate (kbit/s):
8188, 
Maximum upstream rate (kbit/s):
1133, 
Maximum downstream rate (kbit/s):
18152

Comment: Seems like you have a 8Mbps sync speed, a fix to your problems may be to put the DSL modem in G.dmt (or ADSL1) mode instead of ADSL2+ (G 992.x) It's more stable and ADSL1 can provide speeds up to 8Mbit/s (which is your subscription's rate)

Comment: Thank you for support but my huawai HG658 V2 modem doesn't allow me to change line mode. I can't find any way to do this for now.

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot of the main menus, may be you missed it ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Kvnm4

Comment: Seems like the option isnt available. I don't know why they don't want you to set the modulation that you want to use..